# How can I repair staining on a parquetry floor?

Tags: wood, hardwood-floor

My friend spilled water without noticing on my parquetry floor and it had some time (12h) to stain the wood. I wonder, how can I improve the look, remove those dark staining at the edges of each bar. A picture says more than a thousand words:

[image]

**EDIT on January 2014:**
The condition of the parquetry floor improved drastically over time.
Yet some marks are still visible. In our case we do not need to repair it.

[image]

Comment: I cleaned up the spill roughly 12 hours after the spill. The photo was taken right afterwards (the cleaning)

Comment: This could just be moisture from the initial cleaning. Since it's been awhile, did you ever get this problem solved?

Comment: I updated my question to include a photo after 6 month.

Answer (score 1):

If water is absorbing this readily into your floor and discoloring it this much, it's probably time to refinish it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if it doesn't clear up, you'll have to refinish the floor.  This means sanding, restaining and resealing.  Worse than that, if your floor is cheap and can't be sanded, you'd have to replace it.  So cross your fingers.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar with slight shrinkage. Renter had plants and failed at keeping the floor protected. It was too slight to call somebody in....will make it part of another floor job. But there was was some improvement when I slathered it with paste wax, the kind in the can....covered it loosely for a couple of days with a cloth. When I went back it was visibly better, not perfect. Is security deposit one word or two?

Answer (score 0):

Use a product called TSP (Tri-Sodium Phosphate). You can usually pick it up at a local hardware store. I buy it at Sherwin-Williams. You can  mix it with a 50/50 cut of water and bleach to make a concentrated paste. Rub it into the floor and let it set until it dries or overnight. This will bleach the stain out or lighten it up considerably. You're right, the install may have been sloppy, or equally as detrimental is a sloppy floor finish. After the TSP treatment, I recommend using a product called [wood flour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_flour). We use it to seal even the tightest seams in all of our floor installs. Make sure to seal the floor with a good finish.